# Setup Meteor / Meteorite LinkedIn Package?

Tags: oauth, meteor, installation, linkedin-api, meteorite

I've installed the following package:
https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/accounts-linkedin

However, no linkedIn button appears in the `{{> loginButtons}}` ui and `Meteor.loginWithLinkedin` is undefined in chromes's console.

`Meteor.loginWithLinkedin`is defined in the package's file "linkedin_client.js", which lead me to check if the package files are in chrome's sources adn they weren't.  There are no files/folders that I can see for "accounts-linkedin" or the "linkedin" (when installing "accounts-linkedin" "linkedin" was also installed) meteorite packages in chrome's sources panel.

Someone else asked the same question on github three months ago without a response: https://github.com/yefim/meteor-accounts-linkedin/issues/1

Comment: somebody has to fix this, and that somebody is not me

Answer (score 3):

The `accounts-ui` package has to incorporate linkedIn for it to work. At the moment I think it only supports Facebook, Twitter, Github, Weibo, Meetup, and normal Passwords/Usernames. `accounts-linkedin` is a custom package from atmosphere so its not there by default.

You could modify the `accounts-ui` package to take in linkedIn too. You would have to download the package from `https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled` and add this into your project in the `/packages` directory. It should then override the default meteor package.

The `accounts-ui` package just adds styling to the `accounts-ui-unstyled` package just for extra info.

Comment: Thanks Tarang!  I wasn't surprised that accounts-UI wouldn't automatically incorporate linkedIn, however I still don't understand why the linkedIn package files aren't showing up on the client.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: They should be. You should have a new method called `Meteor.loginWithLinkedin` available on the client which brings up the linkedIn Oauth dialog

Comment: I thought they should be as well, however they aren't and the `Meteor.loginWithLinkedin` is not defined in the browser console. I don't understand why.  I can verify the files locally in my project directory and the function definition, but not on the browser.

Comment: It doesn't work like that you need to first install meteorite using `sudo npm install meteorite -g`. Then add in the package `mrt add accounts-linkedin`. More details on atmosphere here: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/app

Comment: I had been using `mrt add accounts-linkedin` the trouble was the `stylus-mixin` package was not successfully installed or uninstalled and seemed to prevent the `accounts-linkedin` from working correctly.  Turns out that `accounts-linkedin` does integrate with `accounts-ui` package.  Thanks again Tarang!